# Uniqe ID in list of indexed 2D/3D Image masks (or 2D/3D matrix) in R

Tags: r, image, dataframe, matrix

I want to make a "global" ID of 2D/3D nuclear masks across a list of images.
When i segment my cells they are numbered from 1:numberOfCellsInEachImage. but I would like to have an uniqe Id for each cells across all images.

I have already tried to make a forloop with a global counter and assigned IDs acording to the counter, but It became a messy large thing that I do not trust compleatly

```
# minimal exampe
img1 = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 15, ncol = 15)
img1[2:3, 2:3] = 1
img1[9:10, 5:6] = 2
img1[2:4, 11:13] = 3
img1
# Example indexed image 1
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     0     0
# [3,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     0     0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
img2 = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 15, ncol = 15)
img2[3:4, 2:4] = 1
img2[10:11, 5:7] = 2
img2[3:5, 11:14] = 3
img2
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [3,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     3     0
# [4,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     3     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     3     3     3     3     0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0

# This is the data structure I have
# 
listOfImages2D = list(img1, img2)
#x = listOfImages2D[[1]]
listOfImages3D = lapply(listOfImages2D, function(x){
  x_out = array(data = 0, dim = c(15, 15, 3) )
  x_out[,,2] = x
  return(x_out)
})
```

```
#What I want
# I want all numbers to become an uniqe ID across images
# All zeros should remain zero
# I use img1[img1 == 0 ] = 0 #after giving uniqe IDs
# Image one should ideally start at 1

# ## desired output 
# listOfImages2D_global_index[[1]]
# # same as above
# 
# listOfImages2D_global_index[[2]]
# # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# # [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # [3,]    0    4    4    4    0    0    0    0    0     0     6     6     6     6     0
# # [4,]    0    4    4    4    0    0    0    0    0     0     6     6     6     6     0
# # [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     6     6     6     6     0
# # [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[10,]    0    0    0    0    5    5    5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[11,]    0    0    0    0    5    5    5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# #[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 
# # the code should also work for 3 dimensions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? It's a little crude in that not every successive index is used (`7` is skipped in this case), but the relative difference between values within each array is maintained, which might be useful. If you want to use every index, that wouldn't be too difficult, but would slow down processing.

```
z <- 0 # need this to initiate the loop
a <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3)
b <- c(0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
g <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)

l <- list(z=z, a=a, b=b, g=g)

# l[-1] <- lapply(l[-1], `dim<-`, c(2, 6))    # 2D 
# l[-1] <- lapply(l[-1], `dim<-`, c(2, 2, 3)) # 3D

for (i in 2:length(l)) {
    lnz <- l[[i]] != 0
#   l[[i]][lnz] <- as.numeric(factor(l[[i]][lnz])) # force successive
    d <- max(l[[i-1]]) - min(l[[i]][lnz])
    l[[i]][lnz] <- l[[i]][lnz] + d + 1
}

l[-1]
# $a
#  [1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3 3 3
# 
# $b
#  [1] 0 5 5 5 0 4 4 4 0 0 0 0
# 
# $g
#  [1] 6 6 6 6 0 0 8 8 0 0 0 0
```